# Random element in get_post_meta array

Tags: array, post-meta

I have a custom field that contains a list of comma separated colors.

I want to randomly select one of those colors.

If get_post_meta returns an array I thought I could randomly pick from that array.

If I try to echo $rand_color_value it just gives me the whole array

How can I randomly select one color from the list in the custom field.

```
    $agrs = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'tag' => 'colors'
    );

    $colorLoop = new WP_Query($agrs);

    if($colorLoop->have_posts()):
        while($colorLoop->have_posts()):
            $colorLoop->the_post();

    $theColor = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colors', false);

    /*random color*/
    $rand_color = array_rand($theColor,1);
    $rand_color_value = $theColor[$rand_color];
    echo $rand_color_value; 

    ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif;?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of comma separated colors"? A `string` of comma separated values? Or do you actually store an `array` in the option? Also what exactly do the variables `$theColor`, and `$theWeight` contain? Try `var_dump(compact('theColor', 'theWeight'));`

Comment: The custom field contains something like: red,green,blue,brown. $theColor should contain the array from the custom field. $theWeight was a typo i have updated it now. From the custom field i want to pick a random colour like red.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the actual data type stored in your meta data, your showing a `string` but you're talking about the option containing an `array`? If it's a `string` then I can tell you what the problem probably is, if it's an `array` then you'll need to do some additional debugging.

Comment: It's a string, in the custom field called 'colors' I type: red,blue,green,brown. I want to randomly pick one of these colours and display it. I thought get_post_meta would return an array showing each color at a separate index in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the content of the meta data is actually a string (according to your comment), your code won't work. [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), respectively [`get_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) will only deserialize the content if it's actually [serialized](http://de3.php.net/serialize).

So, if you can't change how the data is saved, ie make sure that an actual `array` or already serialized content is passed to [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), then you have to manually explode your data into an array:

```
$theColor = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colors', true);
$theColor = explode(',', $theColor);
```

Comment: I thought explode would work but it doesn't seem to. Is it because this is a string at [0] in an array?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I forgot to change the `$single` parameter in the `get_post_meta()` call. I've updated the code in my answer.